# How to remove html elements from instance variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have created a web scraper and when I print the results from my instance variable the "td" elements are not striped. How do I remove these. I have tried

```
cols = [item.replace("'<td>", "") for item in cols]
```

but that didn't work.

The code is like this:

```
def __init__(self):
    pages = range(1, 3000, 1)
    self.url = 'https://marknadssok.fi.se/publiceringsklient?Page={}'.format(pages)

def scrape_site(self):
    #All Columns
    self.datum = []

    #Establish connection
    r = requests.get(self.url)
    html = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

    #Append each column to it's attribute
    table_body=html.find('tbody')
    rows = table_body.find_all('tr')
    for row in rows:
        cols = row.find_all('td')
        cols = [x.text.strip() for x in cols]
        self.datum.append(row('td')[0:1]
    print(self.datum)
```

I have several more instance variable, but haven't included them here.
My inspiration for the appending came from a post here where someone used a similar method when scraping from the twitter.api.

Comment: You mean something like cols.text?

Comment: How would that work, when looking at my code again i suspect that I ignore    
 cols = row.find_all('td')
 cols = [x.text.strip() for x in cols] in the for loop and that it just appends the first td element in each row, and therefor the td elements are showing

Comment: Could I kindly ask you to show me how that would be done? Do I go cols = cols.text? Not sure how that is done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this???:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pages = range(1, 3, 1)
        self.url = 'https://marknadssok.fi.se/publiceringsklient?Page={}'.format(pages)
        print(pages)

    def scrape_site(self):
        #All Columns
        self.datum = []

        #Establish connection
        r = requests.get(self.url)
        html = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

        #Append each column to it's attribute
        table_body=html.find('tbody')
        rows = table_body.find_all('tr')

        #print('Row:', rows)

        for row in rows:
            #print("ROW: ", row)
            cols = row.find_all('td')
#            for td in cols:
#                print('COLS:', td.text)
            cols = [x.text.strip() for x in cols]
#            print("COLS2:", cols)
            self.datum.append(cols[0:1])
        print(self.datum)

def __main__():
    t = Test()
    t.scrape_site()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    __main__()
```